# Groupby and sort within group using pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to sort within group by a date column. With pandas, I can use this code

```
df.groupby('order').apply( lambda x: x.sort_values(by= 'date',ascending=False).head(1) )
```

The problem is that this code can take some minutes.

Comment: In pandas you would rather use `idxmax`

Comment: could you provide sample input/output?